# MVC - filterContext.ExceptionHandled

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Does the filterContext.ExceptionHandled property ever get set to true by MVC or is it only set to true by user code? If so where does this happen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`filterContext.ExceptionHandled` get set to true when an exception is thrown by an action method. By default `HandleErrorAttribute` has been added in `FilterConfig` class which is registered in `Application_Start()`. When an exception occurs, the `OnException` method is called in `HandleErrorAttribute` class.

In `OnException` method, before removing the current HTTP response body by using  `Response.Clear()`, the `ExceptionHandled`  property will set to true.

Below is the default OnException method:

```
public virtual void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
{
    if (filterContext == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("filterContext");
    }
    if (filterContext.IsChildAction)
    {
        return;
    }
    if (filterContext.ExceptionHandled || !filterContext.HttpContext.IsCustomErrorEnabled)
    {
        return;
    }
    Exception exception = filterContext.Exception;
    if (new HttpException(null, exception).GetHttpCode() != 500)
    {
        return;
    }
    if (!ExceptionType.IsInstanceOfType(exception))
    {
        return;
    }
    string controllerName = (string)filterContext.RouteData.Values["controller"];
    string actionName = (string)filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"];
    HandleErrorInfo model = new HandleErrorInfo(filterContext.Exception, controllerName, actionName);

    filterContext.Result = new ViewResult
    {
        ViewName = View,
        MasterName = Master,
        ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary<HandleErrorInfo>(model),
        TempData = filterContext.Controller.TempData
    };
    filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
    filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Clear();
    filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 500;
    filterContext.HttpContext.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a source for "filterContext.ExceptionHandled get set to true when an exception is thrown by an action method"?

Comment: I think that OP meant that whatever code handles the exception should set ExceptionHandled to true.